# Как сохранять значение после выхода?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Почему не сохраняется `RatingBar` так как я сделал оценку, но после выхода из приложения у меня снова оценка  1, а не 4, то есть не сохраняет!

Comment: Опишите подробнее свою реализацию сохранения и загрузки оценки.

Comment: А как сделать сохранение и загрузку оценки?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Вот сделал сохранение RatingBar

```
public class RatEl extends Activity {
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ratingBar.setRating(load());
        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean fromUser) {


                textView.setText(""+v);
                save(v);
            }
        });

    }
    public void save (float f){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("folder",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putFloat("rating",f);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public float load(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("folder",MODE_PRIVATE);
        float f=sharedPreferences.getFloat("rating",0f);
        return f;

    }
}
```

Comment: В чем настолько принципиальное отличие от того что предложил я, что аж галку забирать надо было?

Comment: Это абсолютно тот же код, только разделённый на 2 метода...

Comment: Ну мне такой удобнее )

Answer (score 8):

Можно это реализовать так:

```
// Java 7
private final String KEY_RATING = "KEY_RATING";
private final String RATING_PREFS_FILE = "RATING_PREFS_FILE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.myRatingBar);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(RATING_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ratingBar.setRating(prefs.getFloat(KEY_RATING, 0));
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar1, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            prefs.edit().putFloat(KEY_RATING, rating).apply();
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
//Java 8
private final String KEY_RATING = "KEY_RATING";
private final String RATING_PREFS_FILE = "RATING_PREFS_FILE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.myRatingBar);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(RATING_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ratingBar.setRating(prefs.getFloat(KEY_RATING, 0));
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((ratingBar1, rating, fromUser) -> 
        prefs.edit().putFloat(KEY_RATING, rating).apply());
}
```

Также советую почитать про `SharedPreferences` [вот тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Comment: Лови плюсик, парень.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian благодарю

Comment: @zTrap мы с тобой