# как сделать чтобы кнопки шли в ряд

Tags: java, android

У меня такая ситуация - кнопки `ImageButton` идут в низ, а у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы кнопки были в ряд. Что не верно в коде?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_fon1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <ImageView

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="347dp"
            android:layout_height="149dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_log1"
            android:layout_margin="4dp" />

        <com.eugeneek.smilebar.SmileBar
            android:id="@+id/starBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            app:rating="1"
            app:smileDefault="@drawable/none"
            app:smileHeight="50dp"
            app:smileRate1="@drawable/one"
            app:smileRate2="@drawable/two"
            app:smileRate3="@drawable/three"
            app:smileRate4="@drawable/four"
            app:smileRate5="@drawable/five"
            app:smileWidth="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/RbButton.Inverse.Blue"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/otziv" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/vk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vk" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ok" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mail_ru" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/twit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitter" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: У вас невозможная, некомпилируемая разметка. Элементы не могут висеть в пустоте и должны находится в к-л контейнере.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  А как сделать к-л контейнер помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если вы смогли запустить эту разметку на девайсе/эмуляторе, то он у вас есть, просто вы его в вопрос не добавили

Comment: да у меня запускается на эмуляторе

Comment: Значит вы не всю размтеку показали. У вас ваши кнопки в каком-то контейнере уже лежат

Comment: @ЮрийСПб но вот почему то кнопки идут в низ как столбик а  я бы хотел сделать что бы они шли в ряд в линейку

Comment: android:orientation="vertical" поменяйте значение на "horizontal"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробовал  на "horizontal"  не помогло тоже так же

Comment: @tegosyata, не могло не помочь. Возможно у вас `InstantRun` глючит. Отключите его в настройках студии и переустановите приложение.

Comment: хорошо спасибо большое

Comment: @tegosyata, не забудьте принять ответ когда заработает)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хорошо

Comment: Все равно не работает даже при "horizontal"

Comment: Если вы будете переписывать код из чужих ответов в свои, вам перестанут отвечать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас явно указано в разметке что все элементы в контенере должны выстроиться вертикально. Вот тут:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
```

За это ответчает аттрибут `android:orientation`

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Вам надо заменить на `horizontal`, т.е. сделать так:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
```

Comment: Несправедливость :) гляньте на соседний ответ

Comment: @Flippy внимание на [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646663/205238), та же история